# OpenCV 3.0.0 with XCode 6.0 simple code works using putText doesn't

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

Coming from a Windows world, I'm quite new to the OS X environment. I have created a simple OpenCV project with XCode from scratch to only show a video feed, it works. But I wanted to show my students how to insert text in image with the **putText** method and it fails to compile. I have added core, videoio and highgui libs to the project.

The following errors occur
[image: Error]

[image: Specific]

Here is the simple code.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Mat img;
    VideoCapture capture;

    if (!capture.open(0)) {
        cout << "Erreur d'ouverture de caméra\n";
        return -1;
    }

    int c = 0;
    int result = 0;

    bool captureOk = true;

    string winName = "Main window";

    string testString = "TEST!";

    while (c != 27) {

        captureOk = capture.read(img);

        if (captureOk) {

            putText(img, testString, Point(30, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, Scalar(255));

            imshow(winName, img);


        }
        else {
            result = -1;
        }
        c = waitKey(1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In OpenCV 3.0.0, `putText()` is in module [`imgproc`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/imgproc.html), which you `#include`'d through `opencv.hpp`, but did not link. Add the imgproc lib to your project. In OpenCV 2.4.9, `putText()` was still in [`core`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist thanks for helping, but I just tried your solution and it still does not work. The putText error is gone, but it still has the 3 last errors. It's the inputOutputArray and the inputArray which still cause proble.